# If attribute returns empty / null then automatically set it as "N/A" value without if - then condition

Tags: java, loops, null, ldap

Originally, I directly set my attribute value in the getter setter model without testing whether the attribute is empty or null.

```
String urlLDAP = "ldap://localhost:389/";
NamingEnumeration results = null;
Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, urlLDAP);
env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "cn=admin,ou=sa,o=system");         
env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "XXX");
DirContext context = new InitialDirContext(env);
SearchControls controls = new SearchControls();
controls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
results = context.search(recipientDN, "(objectclass=person)", controls);
while (results.hasMore()) {
    SearchResult searchResult = (SearchResult) results.next();
    Attributes attribute = searchResult.getAttributes();
    try{
        Info info = new Info();
        for (user : userList){          

            info.setUserName(attribute.get("fullName").toString());
            info.setdivision(attribute.get("division").toString());
            info.setAttr3(attribute.get("attribute3").toString());
            .
            .
            .
            .
            info.setAttr3(attribute.get("attribute16").toString());


        }
    }catch (NullPointerException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(robotb.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Then, I add in if-else condition for each attribute because I realised not all users contain the same attribute as other users.
For example, User A does not has attribute 4 and 5 but User B has those two attributes.

```
for (user : userList){

        if(attribute.get("fullName").toString() != null)
            info.setUserName(attribute.get("fullName").toString())
        else 
            info.setUserName("N/A");

        if(attribute.get("division").toString() != null)
            info.setdivision(attribute.get("division").toString())
        else 
            info.setdivision("N/A");

        if (attribute3 != null)
        .
        .
        .

        if (attribute4 != null)
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .

        if (attribute16 ! null)
        .
        .
        .

    }
```

However, this causes my code to be very lengthy.
Is there other ways to make it simpler? Sorry for asking silly question such as this
Appreciates your advice

--EDIT

I added if-else condition to avoid hitting the exception such as this

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

When I hit such exception, the looping stop and I cannot read other attributes

Comment: This should also cause NullPointerExceptions as you can't call the toString() method on an attribute that is null.

Comment: are you using java 8? if so you could use Optional.orElse() https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElse-T-

Comment: `Objects.toString(attribute.get("division"), "N/A")`???

Comment: @Mark True. Thanks for reminding me. I will be removing them

Comment: @AshFrench thanks. Will check it out

Comment: @fabian Omg.. thank you. I totally did not think bout this. As I said, I apologise for my lack of knowledge in Java.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way of doing so is to create a method to check the values.

```
private String fixValue(Object input){
    return input != null ? input.toString() : "N/A";
}
```

Then you can use it on your setters:

```
info.setUserName(fixValue(attribute.get("fullName")))
```

If you also want to check empty strings you can overload the fixValue() method with this second one, so it checks also if the atribute is empty when it is an String:

```
private String fixValue(String input){
    Object inputValue = input == null || input.isEmpty() ? null : input;
    return fixValue(inputValue);
}
```

EDIT:

you can just declare a single method like this:

```
private String fixValue(Object input){      
    return input == null || input.toString().isEmpty() ? "N/A" : input.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use can use ? operator of JAVA like this:

```
info.setdivision((attribute.get("division")==null)?"N/A":attribute.get("division").toString());
```

For more info read about ? operator:

http://www.cafeaulait.org/course/week2/43.html

Answer (score 0):

Using `org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils`

```
info.setUserName(StringUtils.defaultIfEmpty(attribute.get("fullName"), "N/A"));
```

Or you could make a private method handling it to reduce the code even more